# cassandra doesn't creates a correct ring for 2 servers (with 2 instances at each)

Tags: cassandra

I'm using cassandra-1.1.

I want to configure a cluster of 4 instances (2 instances on each pc)
I've updated the .yaml file configuration to the following:

```
listen_address = 127.0.0.1 (127.0.0.2)
rpc_port=9160 (9161)
rpc_address=0.0.0.0
```

The brackets are for the second instance on the same pc.

But In this case the nodetool find the only two cassandra instances on
the same pc (and not 4)

```
./nodetool -h 127.0.0.1 -p 8001 ring
```

I've also configured

```
- seeds: "172.10.10.32,172.10.10.33"
```

The same on the two pc's (x.x.x.32 and x.x.x.33).

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your instances are only listening on loopback interfaces (`127.0.0.1` and `127.0.0.2`). Remote nodes will not be able to connect to your local loopback interfaces. Thus, they will not ever be able to learn that the remote instances are running.

If you want remote nodes to be able to connect, you need to listen on external interfaces.

Comment: Thanks. I'm running multiple servers on the same machine. Thus the listing to 0.0.0.0 is better option for me, since I do not have to change internal protocol ports

Comment: You can not use 0.0.0.0 for the listen_address, since it is also used to tell other nodes how to connect back to that node. If all your nodes are on one machine, then using 127.0.0.1, .2, .3, etc is fine, as long as they're all different. You should use those same addresses in the seed list.

Comment: Yes, you right, I'm using 0.0.0.0 for rpm adsress to let the other clients to connect to the cassandra. For configuring two nodes on the same machine I'm using real ip for one node, and 127.0.0.2,3... for another. And in seeds i'm configured the real ips. The problem I have a mixed configuration: 2 machines with 2-3 cassandra instances. Is it seems Ok?

Comment: No, that won't work. The nodes on machine A won't be able to connect to the localhost interface on machine B. If you really have to run multiple Cassandra instances on multiple machines (this is not at all recommended), you will need multiple external network interfaces, so each node can have its own interface and each node can contact every other.

Comment: Thanks, I've configured this but I indeed saw that something is wrong with this configuration. It created the ring of 4, but I experienced a lot of timeout. But if I'll configure this with external ip's why is running multiple cluster on the same machine is not recommended? I have g5 strong server with 32G ram and 8 cpu?

Comment: That should probably be a new top level question, but basically one Cassandra instance should be able to parellelize enough to take advantage of all your node's resources.